# How to code responsive UI for 4K resolution using a small resolution device?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am starting a UI Development project for a web application. The device it is being built to perfectly work on is this monitor http://goo.gl/gUSGec which has 3840 x 2160 px resolution but it also needs to be responsive.The designs I have received are also of this resolution i.e. 3840 x 2160 px. Is there a way to perfectly simulate 4K Resolution? I have planned to use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You could but i think you should customize or extend the grid system with your own values or devices sizes classes. Bootstrap use pixels instead of .em to setup font sizes, probably could be a "problem" in 4k design because the size of your assets can be reduced (Bootstrap v4 will use .em). I havent see getbootstrap.com in a 4k monitor, try and if you like what you see it means you can use it :)